# Stochastic Integral of Simple Predictable Process is a Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Take $H\in S$ to be a *simple process* defined as:
$$H_t:=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} H_i1_{(T_i,T_{i+1}]}(t),\ \  H_i\in \mathcal{F}_{T_i}, \ (T_1\leq...\leq T_n \ stopping\  times),$$

and $X$ a Martingale.
I want to prove that the Stochastic Integral $(H\cdot X)$ defined as:

$$(H\cdot X)_t:=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} H_i(X_t^{T_{i+1}} - X_t^{T_i})$$

is a Martingale.

I have to show that $\mathbb{E}[(H\cdot X)_t|\mathcal{F_s}]=(H\cdot X)_s $,   given that $\mathbb{E}[X_t|\mathcal{F_s}]=X_s$.

Without loss of generality, let's assume:
$$H = H_11_{(T_1,T_{2}]}+H_21_{(T_2,T_{3}]}$$

then,
$$(H\cdot X)_t:= H_1(X_t^{T_{2}} - X_t^{T_1})+H_2(X_t^{T_{3}} - X_t^{T_2})$$
with $T_1\leq s\leq T_2 \leq t \leq T_3$.

Then:
$$\mathbb{E}[(H\cdot X)_t|\mathcal{F_s}]=\mathbb{E}[H_1(X_t^{T_{2}} - X_t^{T_1})|\mathcal{F_s}]+\mathbb{E}[H_2(X_t^{T_{3}} - X_t^{T_2})|\mathcal{F_s}]=$$
$$H_1(X_s^{T_{2}} - X_s^{T_1})+\mathbb{E}[H_2(X_t - X_{T_2})|\mathcal{F_s}].  (*)$$

I get stuck here because $H_2$ is $\mathcal{F_{T_2}}$-measurable and since $s\leq T_2$ I can not bring $H_2$ outside the expectation and apply the martingale property on $X$.

Any hint?

EDIT: This should work

Consider just the *second* addend in (*):

$$\mathbb{E}[H_2(X_t - X_{T_2})|\mathcal{F_s}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[H_2(X_t - X_{T_2})|\mathcal{F}_{T_2}]|\mathcal{F_s}]=\mathbb{E}[H_2\mathbb{E}[(X_t - X_{T_2})|\mathcal{F}_{T_2}]|\mathcal{F_s}]= 0.$$

Therefore:

$$\mathbb{E}[(H\cdot X)_t|\mathcal{F_s}]=H_1(X_s^{T_{2}} - X_s^{T_1})=(H\cdot X)_s,$$

since $$(H\cdot X)_s=H_1(X_s^{T_{2}} - X_s^{T_1})+H_2(X_s^{T_{3}} - X_s^{T_2})=$$
$$H_1(X_s^{T_{2}} - X_s^{T_1})+H_2(X_s - X_s)=$$
$$H_1(X_s^{T_{2}} - X_s^{T_1}).$$

Comment: normally we need $H_t$ to be predictable !  you are not assuming predictability here right ?

Comment: @DaveNguyen Sorry for being not precise, indeed I mean predictable. This is embedded in the fact that $H_i \in \mathcal{F}_{T_i}$

Comment: I think we need to assume $H_{n+1}\in \mathcal{F}_{n-1}$.

Comment: @DaveNguyen that is not possible. I took the definition from Protter, Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations

Comment: your question is just a continuous version of theorem 2.7-page 231 - Durrett's : book : probability -theory and examples. There he assumes predictability.

Comment: @DaveNguyen I have the 4th edition of that book but there is no Theorem 2.7 at page 231

Comment: I have the 3rd version, i think you can find it on line. It is in page 231-theorem 2.7 3rd version ! it is in chapter 4 !

Comment: @DaveNguyen I got the answer